# How do I pass debug and logging options through Faraday to Net::HTTP or Net::HTTPS

Tags: ruby, debugging, logging, faraday

I'm using Faraday and Net::HTTP, Net::HTTPS to connect to a site using SSL. However I get the following error:
'SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A: sslv3 alert handshake failure'

How do I make Faraday turn on debugging and logging in the underlying client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you initialize the `Faraday` connection, you can pass things through to the underlying adapter.  For example, I use this behavior in one of my clients, albeit with `Excon` instead of `Net::HTTP`, but you should be able to adapt:

```
excon_options = {}
excon_options.merge!(instrumentor: instrumentor) if instrumentor
@connection = Faraday::Connection.new(url: url) do |builder|
  builder.adapter :excon, excon_options
end
```

The `excon_options` hash in this case is the format of a hash that I would pass to the `Excon` connection object if I weren't using `Faraday`.  You should be able to do something similar with `Net::HTTP`

Comment: FYI This appears to be a Faraday 0.8.x feature. It does not work on Faraday 0.7.4